# Javascript - Check if suggestions are shown when autocomplete is active

Tags: javascript, html, gwt, autocomplete

I'm trying to detect when a user types in an input with autocomplete, if the suggestions are being shown by the browser.

For example, if a user starts typing in a login form, if some usernames that match the characters were saved, the browser will display the suggestions.

PS. I need this because I use an Ajax request method to login, and I have an issue when users press enter on a suggestion: the form executes a login request directly on key press enter and the browser is showing a dialog box to remember just a part of the username. For example, if a user has chosen to remember "myusername", at the next login, when he presses "my...", the suggestion is show by the browser (for autocomplete), and when the selection is chosen and enter is pressed, the browser asks the user to remember password for "my", but actually it should't have prompted anything because "myusername" was already remembered.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you could do that because browser's suggestions aren't shown in the DOM tree.

You should do your Ajax request when normally form would be submitted. This way you will have full user name already filled by browser's autocomplete. You just need to cancel the submit event and do Ajax request instead:

In GWT:

```
loginForm.addSubmitHandler(new SubmitHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onSubmit(SubmitEvent event) {
        event.cancel();
        // Ajax request here...
    }
});
```